# How to serve file referenced from HTML file using WebBroker (TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge) and TWebModule

Tags: windows, http, delphi

I built tiny http server (Delphi 10.2) to return some calculations to client on-line.
I used page producer with TPageProducer.HTMLFile set to local file.
The **test.html** file has reference to css file on local disk like: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="data/style.css">` in the head section. It works from Firefox styling my html.

To be able to serve this css file from local folder I handled WebModule.BeforeDispatch:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; 
  Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  LocalPath: String;
begin
  if Request.PathInfo.StartsWith('/data/') then
  begin
    LocalPath := DataPath + StringReplace(Request.PathInfo, '/', '\', [rfReplaceAll]);
    if FileExists(LocalPath) then
    begin
      Response.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create(LocalPath, fmShareDenyWrite);
      Assert(Response.ContentStream.Size > 0);
    end;
    Handled := True;
  end;
end;
```

When I run my server and go to address: http://localhost/data/style.css
I obtain proper contents of **style.css** file in a browser window as a result.

Why is it not used as style for my HTML file even if it is correctly read in OnBeforeDispatch when using address like http://localhost/test.html?

It seems that one file (CSS) is referenced from other (HTML) and this makes things cluttered.

Comment: "*It works from Firefox styling my html .... Why is it not used as style for my HTML file*" - seems like a contradiction to me

Comment: I have two files: 1) test.html which has has reference to external "data/style.css". When I open test.html in Firefox it loads style.css right. I try do the same with Delphi. I run my http server, in Firefox go to address "localhost/test.html".  My server sends test.html file to Firefox and during parsing test.html Firefox asks next request to obtain data/style.css... And style.css is sent to Firefox too (I can see it watching Delphi transfers and Firefox Network debug window (F12)). But Firefox does not use this style.css and test.html stays unstyled.

Comment: Did you verify your server is sending the correct HTTP headers for `style.css`? Maybe they are wrong and FireFox doesn't know that `style.css` is an actual CSS file? Hard to say since you did not show the actual HTTP traffic

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint in your code at your `if` statement, so you can check the actual value of `Request.PathInfo`...

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right. Thank you for your help. 
I added Response.ContentType := 'text/css'; and problem solved.
This is my first http server so I did not realize that it is not as simple as file server and headers must be provided.